# WinAPI/Direct3D Fullscreen mode goes back to windowed

Tags: c++, winapi, direct3d

I'm switching to fullscreen mode on creating device but when I click on left or right corner of the window/screen it minimizes and goes back to windowed.
What can I do to fix it? I have just started Direct3D/WinAPI programming. It doesn't happen in games I used/use to play.

[image: help]

```
D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));    // clear out the struct for use
d3dpp.Windowed = FALSE;    // program fullscreen, not windowed
d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;    // discard old frames
d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;
d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = MainWindowHandle;    // set the window to be used by Direct3D
d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8;    // set the back buffer format to 32-bit
d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = 800;    // set the width of the buffer
d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = 600;    // set the height of the buffer
d3dpp.FullScreen_RefreshRateInHz = 0; // above 75 to make eyes happier


pd3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, 
    D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
    MainWindowHandle,
    D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
    &d3dpp,
    &pd3ddev);
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: What Windows version? The corners are special in Windows 8.

Comment: Windows XP SP3. It was caused because I didn't hide the caption bar of the window first before going fullscreen. It can be done using _SetWindowLong_